# I am trying to retrieve an array of numbers from an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

When I run the generateData() function, it returns an array of NaN.

```
function generateData(name) {
    var arr = [];
    var t;
    const x = name;
    for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        t = Number(data.data[i].x)
        arr.push(t);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The object -

```
{data: Array(15), errors: Array(1), meta: {…}}
data: Array(15)
0: {Node no.: 1, CenterA: 0, LeftA: 4.36, RightA: 3.86, RoadA: 1.14, …}
1: {Node no.: 2, CenterA: 5, LeftA: 1.71, RightA: 1.57, RoadA: 2.07, …}
2: {Node no.: 3, CenterA: 0, LeftA: 3.79, RightA: 4.79, RoadA: 2.86, …}
3: {Node no.: 4, CenterA: 4.64, LeftA: 5.36, RightA: 2.29, RoadA: 2.5, …}
4: {Node no.: 5, CenterA: 0, LeftA: 4.21, RightA: 4.43, RoadA: 2.14, …}
5: {Node no.: 6, CenterA: 4.86, LeftA: 3.21, RightA: 1.43, RoadA: 2.21, …}
6: {Node no.: 7, CenterA: 0, LeftA: 5.79, RightA: 5.5, RoadA: 2.36, …}
7: {Node no.: 8, CenterA: 5.86, LeftA: 2.71, RightA: 3.21, RoadA: 2.93, …}
8: {Node no.: 9, CenterA: 0, LeftA: 5.29, RightA: 6.64, RoadA: 2.64, …}
9: {Node no.: 10, CenterA: 5.57, LeftA: 1.36, RightA: 2.86, RoadA: 2.07, …}
10: {Node no.: 11, CenterA: 0, LeftA: 5.43, RightA: 5.29, RoadA: 1.5, …}
11: {Node no.: 12, CenterA: 4.43, LeftA: 2.79, RightA: 4.21, RoadA: 3.21, …}
12: {Node no.: 13, CenterA: 0, LeftA: 4.79, RightA: 5.43, RoadA: 2.29, …}
13: {Node no.: 14, CenterA: 0, LeftA: 4.57, RightA: 3.64, RoadA: 2.71, …}
14: {Node no.: null}
```

I need an array which contains all the entries of different columns such as RightA, CenterA, etc.
I used Number() function in the code to convert the entries to a number but it still didn't work

Comment: Because x is string, say x = "LeftA" You cannot use string keys as obj."LeftA". You should write as obj["LeftA"] i.e. obj[x]. In your case data.data[i][x]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = Number(data.data[i].x)
```

in this case, `data.data[i].x` is trying to access the property named `x` of `data.data[i]`, which is equivalent to `data.data[i]['x']`.

You want to access the property of the value of the variable `x`, hence you need to use the bracket notation to access the computed property name:

```
t = Number(data.data[i][x])
```

Otherwise the value will be undefined, unless `data.data[i]` has a property `x` which, still, would lead to an undesired result.

Comment: Thankyou for this! But I', having another issue in using this function. I think I'm messing up somewhere in the scope of variables. I have declared data as a global variable. Now when I try to use this function as one of my object property I am getting this error - **_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at generateData (script.js:25)
    at script.js:66_**  can you help me with this?

Comment: @KartikTyagi that means `data` is undefined, likely thrown here: `data.data`. That means `data` before `data` is undefined. Check where `data` is declared and whether it's accessible.

Comment: `var data;` <-- data is empty. What are you expecting it to do? You are referencing an undefined value.

Comment: I have defined 'data' globally which is the original array of objects in the original question. Now after that, when I defined my function and tried to use it in the code below I got the error message which I mentioned in the previous comment.

`myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: transparentize(220, 20, 60),
            data: generateData('CenterA'), 
            }]
     }
 });`

Comment: @KartikTyagi `data` is probebly overwritten somewhere, try to `console.log` it before the callback to see whether it's available there, using `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));`

Answer (score 1):

Use computed property names:

```
t = Number(data.data[i][x])
```

Comment: Why is this a comment on my answer @DanilaAlpatov?